# NoSuchWindowException after Close Window

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm using robotframework with the Selenium2Library.
And i've been having some trouble on handling popup windows in IE8.

```
Try Popup
    Open Browser To PageXYZ
    Click Element  XYZ
    Select Window name=POPUPXYZ
    Page Should Contain  X
    Page Should Contain  Y
    Page Should Contain  Z
    Close Window
    Get Window Identifiers
```

Any command I use after the 'Close Window' fails and i get the same exception NoSuchWindowException.

(That shouldn't happen for the Get Window command IMO)

Any help?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that it should not happen but it does.
From what I have seen, it is as if WebDriver needs a cool-off period (Sleeps will get rid of the error). As a workaround I use Wait Until Keyword Succeeds in combination with a Selenium2Library keyword that should pass before I resume testing.