# no such window exception after close window

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am unable to select main parent window after closing pop-up window using close window keyword. I tried Wait until keyword succeeds but still I am getting the same issue.

This issue is happening on Chrome,FF,IE can someone please help me to get a workaround for this. I am using selenium 2.43 version with Robot Framework

Close window is closing pop up but at select window step I am getting no such window exception.

I also tried with Wait Until Keyword Succeeds with Close window and select window but no luck.

```
ClickElement popOutLink
afterPopOutClick    Get Window Titles       
popOutWindow}   Get From List   afterPopOutClick    1
Select Window   title = popOutWindow
Close Window
Select Window title = Parent Window
```

Please suggest if you have any work around

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchWindowException after Close Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687499/nosuchwindowexception-after-close-window)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you give your windows a unique identifiers, may be useful in future and has a lot better chance of being error free. 
Add an ID to a window using:

```
Open Browser FF    Window1    google.co.uk
```

Then to switch to that window:

```
Switch Browser    Window1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Zenon, are you saying i need to open pop-up window using open browser method, if i use open browser i need to login back again as selenium opens a new page without cookies.

Comment: Try and make an ID for the main window so you can switch to it. Is it being opened in a new window or in the same window? 
If it is in a new window this will work. Need a bit more info to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Detailed Info: Close Window keyword is closing the window but any action after close window is giving exception. So I tried to use javascript to close the window using popout = window.open("popwindowid");popoutclose() but it is actually opening a new window instead of closing existing window. So I was looking for any work around to handle the issue.

Comment: Have you tried a sleep as suggested in the answer of the question in the comment on your question?~

Other than that I would need to see the html/javascript code that opens the window to help further. Hopefully you have already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

${handles}   Get Window Titles

Switch Window   ${handles}[1]     ### give the index of required tab to close

Reload Page

Execute Javascript    window.close('https: URL of required tab to close')